# Jquery not defined timing issues

Tags: jquery

I am including jQuery in the head of a personal site.  I also included an external js file right after it that uses jQuery.

```
<script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../js/global.js"></script>
```

global.js merely contains the following:

```
$(".nav-item").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

When I tried it out, I was noticing that my error console was giving me a "$ is not defined error".  After moving my external js file to the bottom of the page, everything works fine.  What is the proper way to deal with what is apparently a timing issue?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT: It seems that while I did see the undefined error last night, I must have done something to get rid of it and am not able to see or reproduce it anymore.  I tried binding the events to document.ready, and that seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Is jQuery being included *later* in the page as well...any chance the first link isn't correct? They should load in order, many things depend on this being the same.  As a side note, `language="javascript"` is deprecated, you should use `type="text/javascript"` instead.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, if the order is correct (custom script AFTER jQuery) you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I apologize for the misinformation. I was no longer receiving the error, and binding the event handler to document.ready fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you bind the event handler in global.js to document ready?

Comment: That's a completely different problem, his issue is $ not being defined. $(document).ready() would still throw "$ is not defined".

Comment: I realize that and it doesn't make sense to me, but due to lack of information this is what I'd advise until he posts more.